# Given a range of cells, Count the row if the column A cell in this row is greater than value in the corresponding column B cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have two columns, A and B, both with a list of numbers. I simply want a formula to count how many times the values in column A are greater than the same row for column B, i.e. A1>B1, A2>B2, A3>B3... etc.

I know how to do it by including a third column, but I'd just like everything in one neat cell if possible.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A>B:B))
```

but to speed things up, restrict the column size like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A100>B1:B100))
```